# Is there a systematic way to find the range of functions?

Tags: functions

I was looking for steps or a systematic way to find the range of functions.

The way to find domain is quite obvious: exclude x-values that make the function undefined on the real numbers.

But the range is harder, I found several methods to find range:

$1)$ Intuition: to guess how the function behaves.

$2)$ Graph: to graph the function and get the range from it.

$3)$ Using limits and calculus to determine the min and max, and how the function behave at infinity.

$4)$ Domain of Inverse of function.

But the problem is there are some functions really hard to get their inverses. And I want to find the range analytically without graphs, limits or calculus tools.

Is there any systematic and direct way to find the range of functions ?

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: This is a very broad question though. It really depends on the difficulty of the function. Generally I would say: First graph. That's why we have graphing calculators these days. Once the graph shows some interesting features regarding max/min and asymptotic behavior, we can (or must) resort to calculus to confirm what the graph is showing. From there we ought to be able to establish a Range

Comment: @imranfat: So, there is no fixed steps to follow ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go by fixed steps, you should do a proper analysis of the function. Back in the days at my school that meant the following:

1) State Domain
2) Investigate y-intercept
3) Investigate x intercept(s)
4) Investigate when the curve is above/under x-axis
5) Investigate vertical asymptotes/holes in the graph
6) State derivative
7) State Domain derivative
8) Make a numberline and determine intervals when function is increasing/decreasing
9) Determine max/min
10) Consider limits $x$ goes to infinity's, horizontal asymptotes?
11) Possibility of slant asymptotes or other asymptotic behavior.
12) Make a graph (nowadays use a calculator)
13) Determine Range

An option would be second derivative but in my school that was not standard on the list unless specified by the teacher.
Hope this helps

Comment: So, there is no direct way for this target except making full analysis. Thanks a lot.